# ~から ~まで for sizes and other non-time related subjects

Tags: particles, grammar, particle-から, particle-まで

I was writing a text about sumi-e pencils and I came up with this sentence:

筆のタイプには、ほうきの大きさからえんぴつの大きさまでがあります。

Trying to convey "As for pencil types, there are pencils from the size of a broom to the size of a (writing) pencil". Can I use ~から ~まで like this?

Answer (score -1):

You are trying to convey size, where is サイズ?

> 筆のサイズには、ほうきの太さからえんぴつ位の細さまであります。

> Brush sizes range from the thickness of a broom to the thinness of a pencil.

Dr. Google agrees this would be acceptable.

Comment: There's no need to explicitly say「サイズ」because the sentence already mentions「大きさ」. Also, if you used Google to check or verify your findings, the least you could do is add some sources to your answer for OP to look into.